# Return file download is requested twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, download

After hours of searching the error I'm able to isolate the problematic code part. If I call this action, then the "Hit" data record is added twice (only if I run with `return File(...)`):

```
public class ShowController : Controller
{
    private PictureDBContext ctx = new PictureDBContext();

    public ActionResult Pic(string accesscode)
    {
        var pic = ctx.Pictures.Include(h=>h.Hits)
            .Where(p => p.AccessCode == accesscode).FirstOrDefault();
        if (pic == null) throw new HttpException(404, "NotFound");
        pic.Hits.Add(new Hit { Date = DateTime.Now });
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        return File(Path.Combine(pic.PhysicalPath + pic.FileName), "image/jpeg");
        //return View();
    }
}
```

Models:

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...props removed for readability
    public List<Hit> Hits { get; set; }
}
public class PictureDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Hit> Hits { get; set; }
}
public class Hit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    //public int Picture_Id { get; set; }
    //public Picture Picture { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see... no magic inside. 
If i replace `return File(...)` with `return View()`, then the data is inserted correctly only once. As soon as I use `return File(...)` the Hit data record is added twice. What's going on here, what did I miss?

Edit: Added the class-code for Picture and Hits

Comment: Is it "Hit added twice" or is the method itself executed twice?

Comment: I added a logfile function... the method is executed only once.

Comment: not answering the question, but this method is not scalable, it's getting slower and slower because `Hits` is included just for adding a new Hit, probably you need to fix that later to work with disconnected object

Comment: @YuliamChandra If AccessCode is indexed, and only the First is fetched..?

Comment: Thank you Yuliam for this hint. I will consider this in the future.

Comment: @user2864740, probably fine in the db, but they're loaded into memory, anyway, try to reconfirm whether the method is really only called once when it's accessed, probably you could adding something like `File.AppendAllText("C:\\test.txt", "hit" + Environment.NewLine);` and check the file (not sure what kind of log you use)..

Comment: Can you confirm the date value is same for both records?

Comment: @Yuliam: Shame on me. The method is really executed twice (i didn't wirte to the file in appending mode).

Comment: @Mathew: The data is inserted with different timestamp (insert timestamp). So its not the 'same' data. Very very strange ....

Comment: If both parties support(client and server),I make a wild guess that `FileResult` may respond `206 partial content` which will result in multiple further range requests. Not at all sure though. Log all the request headers and see.

Comment: Headerlog (one request):
(snipped) -> two complete headers. what to do?

Comment: To make things clearer, you should get rid of the class-level field `ctx` and use a local variable in the `Pic` method. I'd bet that there is a previous insert of `Pic` from some other method call using the same `DbContext`. So when you `SaveChanges()`, both inserts occur.

Comment: @Keith: There is no other open DbContext elsewhere and its reproducible with only this method. I think Mathew is going in the right direction. Method is called more than once because of partial content requests. I will investigate this a little bit more...

Comment: It's getting more strange. This situation i can reproduce only with small .png image files. With larger files (>100kb) there is no problem. Maybe this info helps?

Comment: No solution for me? :-(

Comment: How did the client request the page ? Using a browser directly type the url ? Using ajax and `download button` in the UI you provided ?

Comment: @YuliamChandra: I type the url directly into the browser (firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can replicate it in Firefox 31 (but not in Chrome 37), not sure what happened. In Firefox it requests twice, in Chrome only once.

I tried specifying `fileDownloadName` parameter and it only requests once, but there will be a popup in the browser.

```
public ActionResult Pic()
{
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("D:\\test.txt", "test" + Environment.NewLine);
    return File("D:\\Untitled.png", "image/png", "Untitled.png");
                                                     ^^^
                                                // Add this
}
```

[image]

The popup doesn't appear on Chrome.

Hope that helps.

**Update**

This is an open bug in Firefox.

[Bug 583351 - Firefox sends GET request twice to server for a dynamically-generated small PNG image](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=583351)

A comment from Daniel Nunes:

> That's because Firefox won't show a preview image in the tab's favicon
>   if any dimension of the image is 1024 pixels or higher. It's the
>   favicon where the second request comes from.

Comment: I tested it and can confirm that the method this way only gets executed once. File open dialog appears in IE8 and FF 18.0.1. This popup makes the whole function useless, the picture should displayed directly in the browser window without popup. I will try another way (e.g. memorystream?).

Comment: @Ted, it's a bug in firefox, if the image size > 1024 there will only 1 request, check my update

Comment: Thank you so much for the update! I will mark your post as the answer.